# Elegant way to convert dictreader to a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

I am doing this:

```
headers = ['name', 'accum', 'hi', 'active', 'first', 'last', 'max', 'dirty']
filename = "C:\\Users\\bcrafton\\Desktop\\se0sh0cb0_perf.vec"

with open("C:\\Users\\bcrafton\\Desktop\\se0sh0cb0_perf.vec") as csvfile:

    for line in csvfile:
        if all(header in line for header in headers):
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
            break
```

which works great.

But I would rather not have to keep the file open in order to use my data. Is there elegant way, that will just put my data in RAM rather than needing the file to be open?

Ideally I would like to be able to just close the file, and then be able to access my data doing something like this

```
table['name']['address']
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you've left out some essential details, I went ahead and made a few assumptions resulting in this:

```
table = {}

with open("C:\\Users\\bcrafton\\Desktop\\se0sh0cb0_perf.vec") as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        if all(header in line for header in headers):
            for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=headers):
                name_row = table.get(row['name'], {})
                name_row[row['name']] = row['address']
```